# how to remove a text before a character or string on a CSV file using batch

Tags: csv, batch-file, text

I have a CSV file that I want to modify using batch to remove a string basically I have the next

```
randomID1, randomID2, randomID3, networkinterface, othercolumn1, othercolumn2,
abc123AAB, 098189909, 999181818, net on Server123, FORCED, anotherthing,
abc2455aB, 848449388, 123131232, LocalNet on SEV1, FORCED, otherlessstuff,
```

My relevant caracthers are Server123 and SEV1, so I need to convert the above on

```
randomID1, randomID2, randomID3, networkinterface, othercolumn1, othercolumn2,
abc123AAB, 098189909, 999181818, Server123, FORCED, anotherthing,
abc2455aB, 848449388, 123131232, SEV1, FORCED, otherlessstuff,
```

This means removing 'net on ' and 'LocalNet on ' strings.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Batch language is far from ideal for this, but here's a basic script to simply line-by-line remove occurrences of *"net on "* and *"LocalNet on "* from *input.txt* and save the result as *output.txt*:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
TYPE NUL > output.txt
FOR /F "delims=" %%L IN (input.txt) DO (
  SET LINE=%%L
  SET LINE=!LINE:LocalNet on =!
  ECHO/!LINE:net on =!>> output.txt
)
```

Refinements are possible and may be needed. E.g., this won't work if the file contains reserved characters such as `&`. And it's not case sensitive. The latter is the reason the *"LocalNet on "* substitution is done before the *"net on "* substitution which is a substring when case insensitive. There's nothing CSV specific here because from your question that doesn't appear to be required. But if for example you needed to treat different comma-separated tokens differently, that can be done with a `"delims=,"` option and some extra code.

Comment: @Hugo, have you had a chance to see if this works for you? If so please consider marking the answer accepted. [Here's why](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/317538) that's worthwhile.